# onMouseUp, onRightClick, onDblClick fired simultaneosly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `@react-google-maps/api`

When I put the three callbacks together on a Polygon component like this

```
const callBacks = useEventCallback(t => {
    console.log(t);
  });
  return (
    <Polygon
      {...otherProps}
      {...callBacks}
      path={path}
      editable={disabled ? false : true}
      onLoad={poly => {
        polyRef.current = poly;
      }}
    />
  );
```

Also the useEventCallback

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
type CallbackType = "mouse_up" | "double_click" | "right_click" | null;
function useEventCallback(onChange: (type: CallbackType) => void) {
  const [currentCallback, setCallback] = useState<CallbackType>();
  function handleChange(e: any, type: CallbackType) {
    setCallback(type);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;

    if (!timer) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(currentCallback);
      }, 100);
    }
  }, [currentCallback]);

  const onMouseUp = useCallback((e: any) => handleChange(e, "mouse_up"), [
    handleChange,
  ]);

  const onDblClick = useCallback((e: any) => handleChange(e, "double_click"), [
    handleChange,
  ]);

  const onRightClick = useCallback((e: any) => handleChange(e, "right_click"), [
    handleChange,
  ]);
  return {
    onRightClick,
    onMouseUp,
    onDblClick,
  };
}
```

When I right click a point

[image]

PS. The event objects are **IDENTICAL**, there is no way to differentiate between them.

Is there any way to not call on_mouse up when right_click event is called.?

Comment: Because you are using `handleChange` same callback function. Create mouseUpHandler 
 onDblClickHandler etc...

Comment: @NikolaLukic. Hey thats not the issue. it is being called MULTIPLE times. That is the issue. I tried using seperate callbacks but even then they are being called multiple times